# Allow int numbers in @textboxfor with no comma or point

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I created a Razor page with a @html.textboxfor that I want to allow only numbers. I changed the type to number, but still, when testing it, it will accept comma and point. I tried some onchange functions to get the value from that textbox, replace all commas or points with nothing, and return to the same textbox. I managed to do that using a second textbox just for testing, but I don't want that behavior. I want the textboxfor to have the same behavior as when I try to type any letters. Which means, do nothing. I just started learning C#/Asp.net, and I couldn't find anything on google. Maybe I'm not searching for the right names, so any tips or directions on what I should research for would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found something that works perfectly. Just in case anyone wants to use it.

First I created the TextboxFor and removed the number type:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.price, new {  @id = "amount", @onInput = "javascript: replaceComma('amount'); "})
```

Then I added this javascript to replace any non-number char with an empty value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function replaceComma(i) {
        var val = document.getElementById(i).value;
        val = val.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '')
        document.getElementById(i).value = val;
    }
</script>
```

I'm not sure this is the best approach, but it seems to be working now.